# Why when I am changing my navbar position to relative it is not overlapping with my text?

Tags: html, css

I have shown my problem through images So, anyone can answer it would be very helpful as I am a newbie right now. So learning through Youtube.[When I am changing position relative My all the elements presents in navbar get beside the background colour which I have put with the help of before tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zhgm.jpg)

Here is my HTML code which I have used is written dow below:

```
display: flex;
font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
}
.navbar::before {
content: "";
background-color: black;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 22vh;
z-index: -1;
opacity: 0.4;
}
.navbar img {
width: 61px;
height: 47px;
margin: 21px 29px;
}
.navbar ul {
display: flex;
}
.navbar li {
list-style: none;
}
.navbar li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
align-items: center;
margin: 45px 32px;
color: white;
font-size: 1.1rem;
cursor: pointer;
}
.navbar li a:hover {
background-color: rgb(87, 240, 26);
color: black;
font-size: 1.3rem;
border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Please share the html code

Comment: please share a snipped with your code so we can see what's wrong, you only shared a small & incomplete part of your CSS here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove the pseudo-elemenet `::before` on the `.navbar` and move the `background-color:black` to be defined within the `.navbar` styles.

Instead of setting the background to black, set it to an RGBa value to give the colour an opacity, for example:

```
.navbar{
   background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 40%);
   display:flex;
}
```

This will make the items in the navbar sit on top of the background colour.

Comment: Thanks I will try first